# Use templates in Python Bottle

Tags: python, jinja2, bottle

Currently, I use Python Bottle in one of my projects. I want to change it and use templates like Jinja2 tutorials with extends and includes to avoid repeating navbars, footers etc.

In Jinja2 I could use something like this:

```
{% extends base.html %}

{% block maincontent %}
<here my HTML code>
{% endblock %}
```

I found that I can use this with Bottle by importing Jinja2 view and template, but then I have to reformat every Python code in HTML pages from Bottle to Jinja2 formats.

For example:

from:

```
%for i in mylist:
<option>{{i}}</option>
%end
```

to:

```
{% for i in mylist %}
<option>{{i}}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

Is there any way to use extends with Bottle template without changing all my Python code? I cannot find any tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The template engine bottle uses, SimpleTemplate, doesn't support inheritance.
You can, however, use [include](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/stpl.html#stpl.include) to separate things like headers and footers, or [rebase](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/stpl.html#stpl.rebase) to simulate inheritance.

Of course, since SimpleTemplate is, well, **simple**, if you know you'll need more advanced templating features, it'll be less costly to migrate now rather than later.

Comment: So, either I keep SimpleTemplate and use include instead of expands or change now to Jinja2 templates. The project is really big now to change and at the moment, I don't know if Jinja2 can give me any advantage, but I will think about it. Thank you